# Incorrect Output, need synchronous for loop

Tags: node.js, promise

```
exports.calculateGstBaseOnInput = function(req, res) {
    console.log("welcome");
    for (var item of req.body.so_items) {
        req.productid = item.productid;
        req.qty = item.qty;
        getItemDetail(req, res).then(function(result) {
            return getCartItems(req, res);
        }).then(function(result) {
            return calculateGST(req, res);
        })
    }
}

getItemDetail = function(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("inside getItemDetail");

        var SQL = "mysql query";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("inside err");

                res.json({ status: 'Failure', statusMessage: 'item does not exist' });
            } else if (result.length < 0) {
                console.log("inside length 0");

                res.json({ status: 'Failure', statusMessage: 'item does not exist' });
            } else {
                req.itemdetail = result;
                console.log("price inside getitemdetail= ", req.itemdetail[0].price);

                //callback();
            }
        });
        resolve('done');
    });
}

getCartItems = function(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("inside getCartItems");
        var SQL = "mysql query";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ status: 'Failure', statusMessage: 'item does not exist' });
            } else if (result.length < 0) {
                res.json({ status: 'Failure', statusMessage: 'item does not exist' });
            } else {
                req.cartItems = result;
                //callback();
            }
        });
        resolve('done');
    });
}

calculateGST = function(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("inside calculateGST");

        if (req.userDetails[0].is_gst_included) {
            //total = req.qty * req.itemdetail[0].price;
            // console.log("price = ",req.itemdetail[0].price);
            //callback();
        } else {
            //total = req.qty * req.itemdetail[0].price;
            //console.log("price = ",req.itemdetail[0].price);
            //total = req.qty * req.itemdetail[0].price;

        }

        resolve('done');
    });
}
```

Actual output :

```
inside getItemDetail
inside getItemDetail
inside getCartItems
inside getCartItems
inside calculateGST
inside calculateGST
```

Expected Output(output i wanted):

```
inside getItemDetail
 inside getCartItems
    inside calculateGST
    inside getItemDetail
    inside getCartItems
    inside calculateGST
```

how do i achieve this without setting any time.

Comment: Show the code that actually calls those functions instead of the function definitions.  You need to learn to use the `.then()` method of Promises or look into using `async/await`.

Comment: read carefully. it is there already. look into the method calculateGstBaseOnInput  where you can find the call to all the function.

Comment: everytime i search for synchronous loops async/await appears but no where i can find an example or documentation of forloops/loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `resolve`ing immediately instead of resolving within the callback provided to `mysqlConnect.query()`.

Consider an abbreviated version of your `getItemDetail` function:

```
function getItemDetail(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var SQL = "mysql query";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
            // Stuff
        });
        resolve('done');
    });
}
```

It's logic is:

1. Create a new promise
2. Begin a `query`
3. `resolve()`
4. Whatever called `getItemDetail` does what it should because `getItemDetail` resolved
5. `query` finishes sometime later

---

Instead, you should likely be doing something like this, where `resolve` is within the `query` callback:

```
function getItemDetail(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var SQL = "mysql query";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
            // Stuff
            resolve('done');
        });
    });
}
```

The logic here is:

1. Create a new promise
2. Begin a `query`
3. `getItemDetail` caller shouldn't do anything yet because `getItemDetail` isn't yet resolved
4. `query` finishes at some point and the callback is triggered which calls `resolve`
5. `getItemDetail` caller will now proceed since it has been told that the function resolved

You need to follow this pattern in any function where you need a query to actually finish before the caller should move on.

---

You should also consider leveraging `async/await`.  Consider this abbreviated example using your code as a base:

```
const mysqlConnect = {
    query(sql, cb) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            cb(null, ["foo"], ["bar"]);
        });
    }
};

(async function() {
    const t = await calculateGstBaseOnInput({
        body: {
            so_items: ["a", "b", "c"]
        }
    });
}());

async function calculateGstBaseOnInput(req, res) {
    for (var item of req.body.so_items) {
        const itemDetail = await getItemDetail(req, res);
        const cartItems = await getCartItems(req, res);
        const gst = await calculateGST(req, res);
    }
}

function getItemDetail(req, res) {
    console.log("getItemDetail");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var SQL = "mysql query";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
            // Stuff
            resolve('done');
        });
    });
}

function getCartItems(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("---getCartItems");
        var SQL = "mysql query";
        mysqlConnect.query(SQL, function(err, result, fields) {
            // Stuff
            resolve('done');
        });
    });
}

function calculateGST(req, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("------calculateGST");
        // Stuff
        resolve('done');
    });
}
```

This outputs:

```
getItemDetail
---getCartItems
------calculateGST
getItemDetail
---getCartItems
------calculateGST
getItemDetail
---getCartItems
------calculateGST
```

Comment: your logic works good for the functions withing a single iteration. But this does not help achieve synchronous loops. I still get the same output.

Comment: my requirement is the loop iterations to be synchronous. second iteration should start execute only after all the functions in the first iteration executed completely.